# Bluetooth speaker (Magicbox) not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

My DKnight Magicbox bluetooth speaker is not working on Ubuntu. It pairs, then after I select it as my output in sound settings, and then click on "test sound" there is no output. The speaker also starts to do a weird clicking sound when it is paired. It works fine on my phone and Windows, just not on Ubuntu. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I got some results swithing off and then switching on the bt speaker with the audio panel open, I see that the bt speaker had wrong modes in the combo box before the off and on switch, after the mode A2DP appear in the modes combo box and selecting this value I can hear the sound from the speaker. The quality is not excellent but is working (may depends on speaker model... mine is very cheap)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/501856)

Comment: @Neil The answer seems to indicate he got it to work. At least a little.